# jquery.active always returns 0 (jquery along with requireJS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, requirejs

In our Selenium automation tests, we use `jquery.active` to check if ajax calls are complete and continue with the test.
However, recently our application was changed to use requireJS.
Since then `jquery.active` always returns 0 irrespective of Jquery Ajax call being in progress.

Please let me know how I can find if there are any pending Ajax calls in progress...?
or solve `jquery.active` always returning zero when using requireJS

```
def ajax_complete(driver):
return 0 == driver.execute_script("return jQuery.active")
```

Answer (score 0):

6 years after the question appeared, but maybe it will help somebody else. I had a similar issue, where I had to make do with whatever info browser dev console provided, while jQuery.active was always = 0, and document.readyState was set to 'complete' before the AJAX calls even began to run. Based on accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49004901/10695261), I was able to build the following solution. Not the most elegant, but it worked so I thought it's worth sharing.

### Base:

First, in a method that returned Boolean, I defined js scripts to be executed that:

- return the number of requests of type "resource"
- return the responseEnd value of the last request of type "resource" on the list

I used "resource" type requests, because these were the requests that I needed to be finished to be able to continue:

```
String jsGetNumberOfRequests = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntriesByType('resource') || {}; return network.length;";
String jsGetLastRequestResponseEndValue = "var performance = window.performance || window.mozPerformance || window.msPerformance || window.webkitPerformance || {}; var network = performance.getEntriesByType('resource') || {}; return network[network.length-1].responseEnd;";
```

add some additional variables for logic purposes along with js executor:

```
String numberOfRequests;
String newNumberOfRequests;
String lastRequestResponseEndValue;
Boolean areRequestsFinished;
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

Then I proceeded with running the scripts and performing the first check - getting the current number of "resource" type requests, and getting the responseEnd value of the last request (getEntriesByType returns requests sorted by connect start time, so technically the last entry on the list would get us the last ran request, but I'd suggest checking on your own whether you need to sort the list first just in case):

```
try {
    numberOfRequests = (js.executeScript(jsGetNumberOfRequests)).toString();
    // in case a particular form has no xhr requests at all (these also happen): 
    if (numberOfRequests.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) { 
        return true;
    }
    lastRequestResponseEndValue = (js.executeScript(jsGetLastRequestResponseEndValue)).toString();
} catch (JavascriptException e) { // we started checking to early
        return false;
}
```

and then all that was left was checking if the last request had a non-empty responseEnd value. And returning the result:

```
if (!lastRequestResponseEndValue.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) { 
    newNumberOfRequests = (js.executeScript(jsGetNumberOfRequests)).toString(); 
    areRequestsFinished = numberOfRequests.equalsIgnoreCase(newNumberOfRequests); 
} else { 
    areRequestsFinished = false;
}

return areRequestsFinished;
```

If not - at least one request is still running. If yes - it's worth checking, if the number of requests didn't change - if it didn't, it's safe to continue with further test steps, if it did - we know that new requests appeared in the meantime that we did not check, so you should re-run the whole thing once more.

### Additionally:

You can wrap it in a **while-loop** or a **custom ExpectedCondition** of Boolean type and use inside an explicit wait (that waits until that condition returns true). You can find info how to create custom ExpectedConditions [here](https://seleniumjava.com/2017/01/06/how-to-create-custom-expected-conditions-in-selenium/).

```
public Boolean waitForAjaxCalls(int timeoutInSec) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(timeoutInSec));
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> customEC = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            //here put the whole body listed above
            //finish with return areRequestsFinished;
        }
    };
    return wait.until(customEC);
}
```